# Qt Signal-Slot interaction.

Tags: qt, signals-slots

Whan I want to use a signal of a private object in order to arise a signal of its parent object I do the following:

```
1. I create a signal and a slot (named, let's say, ParentSignal, ParentSlot)
2. connect(private_objcet, SIGNAL(someSignal()), this, SLOT(ParentSlot()));
3. and define parent slot like this:
```

> ```
> void ParentSlot()
> {
>     emit ParentSignal();
> }
> ```

Is there any way to do this process directly, that is, without ParentSlot?

Comment: You can connect signal to signal: [http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qobject.html#connect](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qobject.html#connect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QObject::connect(private_object, SIGNAL(someSignal()), this, SIGNAL(ParentSignal()));
```

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect